# How to append a div attribute dynamically with imported data with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I want to be able to use data from specific cells brought in from a google sheet (which I was able to do importing with json 'cells") to adjust a width attribute on a div that controls a progress bar.  For example, there are math functions inside the google sheet that calculate the percentage of a completed goal.

I’d like to use those cells (lets say cell d12) to append the css (<div id="bar1" class="progress-bar thm-bg progress-bar-striped wdth’”FROM CELL VALUE”>).  Each bar has a unique div id (bar1,2,3,4, etc.) which need a different progress value.  Lastly, I just want to do increments of 5% progress on the bar.  What is the best way to do this with javascript so that everything can be updated through the google sheet.  Is there a function that can do this?

Comment: Could you post your code some far?

Comment: Sure, I'm bringing in the google sheet with const onDataLoaded = (data) => { with the src being the google sheet.  I then have (sample): const c25Content = data.feed.entry.find((entry) => entry.title.$t == 'C25').content.$t
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = c25Content     This is for all the cells to give me totals.  I want to amend the div class style (<div id="bar1" class="progress-bar thm-bg progress-bar-striped wdth’”FROM CELL VALUE”>) with the percent values from the google sheet but only in increments of 5% as the values on the google sheet increase.

Comment: I also need to strip off the "%" on the cell value so that the "wdth" value is a basic integer.

Comment: In the end, if cell d12 on the google sheet is "14" I need the wdth" value inside <div id="bar1" class="progress-bar thm-bg progress-bar-striped wdth’”FROM CELL VALUE”> to round up to 15 so that is says "wdth15."